# Looping over dictionary of dictionaries - XES file

Tags: python

I have eventlog file (called:filtered_log_offer) type xes which in essence is a dictionary of dictionaries. I want to print the concept:name of the 'attributes', i used to do so through below code but its not working any more, I am not sure what is going on or what I am doing wrong.

when printing the file structure i get the below:

```
print(filtered_log_offer)
[{'attributes': {'concept:name': 2015014, 'custID': 4531}, 'events': [{'time:timestamp': Timestamp('2020-11-19 10:08:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'org:resource': 1344, 'concept:name': 'Offer sent out of the system'}, '..', {'time:timestamp': Timestamp('2020-12-18 12:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'org:resource': 1168, 'concept:name': 'Rejection of a variant'}]}, '....', {'attributes': {'concept:name': 2015923, 'custID': 4531}, 'events': [{'time:timestamp': Timestamp('2020-11-19 10:08:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'org:resource': 1344, 'concept:name': 'Offer sent out of the system'}, '..', {'time:timestamp': Timestamp('2020-12-18 14:59:00+0000', tz='UTC'), 'org:resource': 1344, 'concept:name': 'Sending a decision letter'}]}]
```

Each dictionary represent trace, which start with 'attributes' as dictionary and then 'event' which is list of dictionaries. To loop over the traces and print the case:concept:name I used to do simple loop as follows:

```
print("the transactions that started with 'Offer sent out of the system'")
for i in range(len(filtered_log_offer)):
    print(filtered_log_offer[i][0]['case:concept:name'])
```

and the results would be as I want:

```
the transactions that started with 'Offer sent out of the system'
2015014
2015923
```

now when running the same code I am getting keyError below:

```
the transactions that started with 'Offer sent out of the system'

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-40-048ee2d9409f> in <module>
          4 print("the transactions that started with 'Offer sent out of the system'")
          5 for i in range(len(filtered_log_offer)):
    ----> 6     print(filtered_log_offer[i][0]['case:concept:name'])
          7 
          8 
    
    ~\Anaconda3\envs\process_mining\lib\site-packages\pm4py\objects\log\obj.py in __getitem__(self, key)
         58 
         59     def __getitem__(self, key):
    ---> 60         return self._dict[key]
         61 
         62     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    
    KeyError: 'case:concept:name'
```

I know the name "case" is not present in the 'concept:name' but my problem in another word is that when looping my print is bypassing the 'attributes' dictionary and giving me only the events part of every trace. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The key `'case:concept:name'` is not present in your `self._dict`.

Comment: I know that, but when looping I am not able to access the 'attributes' part, the code is skipping it and accessing the 'event' list of dictionaries - thanks for mentioning it, i will update the question to explain it

Comment: Please read [mre]. Make a copy-pasteable example of your dictionary, that is standalone, and show code that runs on *that*. This will help you get an answer much faster.